# How to change Clojurescript cljs.main source path?

Tags: clojurescript

I'm following [clojurescript.org's Quick Start](https://www.clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start) to build a small app.

By default `cljs.main` wants your CLJS to live directly under `src` (non-standard):

[image: cljs.main default directory structure]

The compilation command the guide offers is:

```
clj --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl
```

My question is simple: **How can I specify that the source root path as `src/main/cljs` rather than the default of `src`?**

I've searched high and low and tested everything I can think of and can't figure out how to make this seemingly simple change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the path in the file `deps.edn`, which needs to be located in the top level folder of your project, like this:

```
.
├── deps.edn
└── src
    └── main
        └── cljs
            └── hello
                └── core.cljs
```

The contents of `deps.edn` are like this:

```clj
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.758"}}
 :paths [:cljs-paths]
 :aliases {:cljs-paths ["src/main/cljs"]}}
```

The example file:

```clj
(ns hello.core)

(println "Hello CLJS from hello.core")
```

I'll compile and run the example from NodeJS, so I pass a flag (`--target node`) to set NodeJS as the runtime target:

```
$ clj -m cljs.main --target node --output-to core.js -c hello.core
WARNING: When invoking clojure.main, use -M

$ node core.js 
Hello CLJS from hello.core
```

The complete reference for the contents of the file `deps.edn` can be found on: https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli and there's a section on how to configure paths for source, resource and test folders.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I found I also needed to upgrade my `clj` version from `1.10.1.536` to `1.10.758` in order for `:aliases` to work (only `:paths` would work with the older version).